# Jquery attr wont work in my function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that runs every five seconds. after it has run away, it looks like prewhour variable is not fetching the latest value, even though I updated it and in my source code is also the most recent value placed.

I have tried to test

```
prewhour2 = $ ("# hour"). attr ("data-now");
```

then, in google chrome consol, works perfectly.

but, when properly into countTo function min, it will not quite work, and I get:
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

appears that countto feature my not quite let it work. can anyone help me find out why? ( the data("now") works but it seems like it dosent get the newest value from it, after re-running the function.

the currhour is just a number to test with, that works flawless.

```
prewhour = $("#hour").data("now");
$('#hour').countTo({
    from: prewhour,
    to: currhour,
    speed: 2000,
    refreshInterval: 50,
    onComplete: function (value) {}
});
$("#hour").attr('data-now', currhour);
```

code:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.countTo = function (options) {
        // merge the default plugin settings with the custom options
        options = $.extend({}, $.fn.countTo.defaults, options || {});
        // how many times to update the value, and how much to increment the value on each update
        var loops = Math.ceil(options.speed / options.refreshInterval),
            increment = (options.to - options.from) / loops;
        return $(this).each(function () {
            var _this = this,
                loopCount = 0,
                value = options.from,
                interval = setInterval(updateTimer, options.refreshInterval);

            function updateTimer() {
                value += increment;
                loopCount++;
                $(_this).html(addCommas(value.toFixed(options.decimals)));
                if (typeof (options.onUpdate) == 'function') {
                    options.onUpdate.call(_this, value);
                }
                if (loopCount >= loops) {
                    clearInterval(interval);
                    value = options.to;
                    if (typeof (options.onComplete) == 'function') {
                        options.onComplete.call(_this, value);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };
$.fn.countTo.defaults = {
    from: 0, // the number the element should start at
    to: 100, // the number the element should end at
    speed: 1000, // how long it should take to count between the target numbers
    refreshInterval: 100, // how often the element should be updated
    decimals: 0, // the number of decimal places to show
    onUpdate: null, // callback method for every time the element is updated,
    onComplete: null, // callback method for when the element finishes updating
};
})(jQuery);
```

edit, total code:

```
function updateInformation() {
    var request_url = 'http://www.lucianomafia.no/accessgambling';
        $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: request_url,
    dataType : 'json',
            data: {  location: '<?echo $data->location?>', type: 'blackjack' },


    success: function(response){
            $("#lastestGames").html(response.table);
        prewhour2 = $("#hour").attr("data-now");


        prewhour = $("#hour").data("now");
        prewday = $("#day").data("now");
        prewweek = $("#week").data("now");
        prewtotal = $("#total").data("now");

        currhour = response.hour;
        currday = response.day;
        currweek = response.week;
        currtotal = response.total;


        jQuery(function($) {
                    $('#hour').countTo({
                        from: prewhour,
                        to: currhour,
                        speed: 2000,
                        refreshInterval: 50,
                        onComplete: function(value) {
                        }
                    });
            $('#day').countTo({
                from: prewday,
                to: currday,
                speed: 2000,
                refreshInterval: 50,
                onComplete: function(value) {
                }
            });
            $('#week').countTo({
                from: prewweek,
                to: currweek,
                speed: 2000,
                refreshInterval: 50,
                onComplete: function(value) {
                }
            });
            $('#total').countTo({
                from: prewtotal,
                to: currtotal,
                speed: 2000,
                refreshInterval: 50,
                onComplete: function(value) {
                }
            });
        });
        $("#hour").attr('data-now',currhour);
        $("#day").attr('data-now',currday);
        $("#week").attr('data-now',currweek);
        $("#total").attr('data-now',currtotal);


    },



    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
    }
});

}


function update(){
    setInterval(function(){updateInformation()},5000);
}
update();
```

Comment: You are fetching using `.data()` and saving using `.attr()`, Note: These are not same.

Comment: Your code works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/jr70oLtt/

Comment: @JohannesReuter i have to get it work by attr too. since , the data dont seems to get their new value, after updating the data-now , and re-running it, it would still be the old value.

Comment: Check the fiddle - there in the data-now attribute is the new value at the end (1239)

Comment: @JohannesReuter, try to re-run the function each 5 sec, and try to get a new value every time. lets say the new value first time is 100, then changing data-now to 100, and then next time 200 etc.

Comment: @JohannesReuter when im re-running my function, it seems like it will not get the newest data-now value using the data("now").

Comment: @JohannesReuter I have edited my main thread description. As you see. lets say first time its running the prewhour is 22, and the currhour is 30.
this works fine. 

but when its re-doing its job. it will get the new currhour ( for example 40), but it will still get the prewhour of 22, even that the prewhour were updated( and its updating propertly), when it should get 30 as prewhour.

Answer (score 0):

as Satpal said in the comments above, you can't get a value via `.data()` when you set it via `.attr()`. These functions should not be mixed for saving and retrieving.

The [data](http://api.jquery.com/data/)-function is used to store data to dom-elements. Data stored via this function can't be seen in your html-markup. This function accept any javascript-type as the value (except `undefined`).

Whereas the [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)-function add a new attribute to html-elements. This can be seen in your html-markup. As in the reference described, `.attr()` allow you to set an object of attributes und values and set the values via a return-value from a function.

Data set with `.attr()` can be retrived with `.data()` but not the other way round. But i would highly recommend not to mix these two.

For your code:

```
prewhour = $("#hour").data("now");
//or
prewhour = $("#hour").attr("data-now");
$('#hour').countTo({
    from: prewhour,
    to: currhour,
    speed: 2000,
    refreshInterval: 50,
    onComplete: function (value) {}
 });
 $("#hour").data('now', currhour);
 //or
  $("#hour").attr('data-now', currhour);
```

**I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kve3qsLp/1/) with an example of your code.** (I had to remove the ajax-call and the countTo-function, but it seems to be working).
If this doesn't help you, perhaps there is an error in your ajax-response or in the countTo-function.

Comment: I have edited my main thread description. As you see. lets say first time its running the prewhour is 22, and the currhour is 30.
this works fine. 

but when its re-doing its job. it will get the new currhour ( for example 40), but it will still get the prewhour of 22, even that the prewhour were updated( and its updating propertly), when it should get 30 as prewhour.

Comment: can you try to get it working, but with the countTo-function aswell? perhaps it wont work for you then?

Comment: @user3199857 I can give it a try when you can provide a working sandbox. I tried to get this function running in my fiddle but something seems to be missing in the code you posted (the function `addCommas()` does not exist)

Comment: @user3199857 I updated my fiddle with the newest version of [countTo](https://github.com/mhuggins/jquery-countTo/blob/master/jquery.countTo.js), it seems to be fine for me. Just try to update your code with the newest version. (I hope I found the right plugin)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/780qj8r6/4/

look there. there you see my problem, that the "old" wont show the value it should.
http://prntscr.com/57kpdz

Comment: @user3199857 as I said: pls avoid mixing `.attr()` and `.data()`, here a updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3rtnjnbb/)